# Placing figures on a fixed place without lot of space around it

Tags: floats

When I use a figure in an document I want to see the figure at the place where I define it. For this I use the `begin{figure[H]`, the problem is that there it happens often that there is a lot of white space around the figure an that the text continues at the bottom of the page. I would like the text to follow the figure directly which might result in some white space at the bottom of the page when the next image doesn't fit.
In a comment on another issue it was advised(@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz) to use `begin{figure[htbp]` though the problem is that at that moment the figures float through the document and don't land at the desired place.

For this I created an example showing the problem (I repeated a building block 20 time so unfortunately it is a bit large, sorry):
MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\makeatletter
\def\figcaption{%
\H@refstepcounter{figure}%
\@dblarg{\@caption{figure}}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libe
\begin{figure}[H]%
  \begin{centering}%
    \includegraphics[width=8cm]{example-image}
    \figcaption{Main window}
  \end{centering}%
\end{figure}%

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libe
\begin{figure}[H]%
  \begin{centering}%
    \includegraphics[width=8cm]{example-image}
    \figcaption{Main window}
  \end{centering}%
\end{figure}%

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libe
\begin{figure}[H]%
  \begin{centering}%
    \includegraphics[width=8cm]{example-image}
    \figcaption{Main window}
  \end{centering}%
\end{figure}%

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libe
\begin{figure}[H]%
  \begin{centering}%
    \includegraphics[width=8cm]{example-image}
    \figcaption{Main window}
  \end{centering}%
\end{figure}%

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libe
\begin{figure}[H]%
  \begin{centering}%
    \includegraphics[width=8cm]{example-image}
    \figcaption{Main window}
  \end{centering}%
\end{figure}%

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libe
\begin{figure}[H]%
  \begin{centering}%
    \includegraphics[width=8cm]{example-image}
    \figcaption{Main window}
  \end{centering}%
\end{figure}%

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libe
\begin{figure}[H]%
  \begin{centering}%
    \includegraphics[width=8cm]{example-image}
    \figcaption{Main window}
  \end{centering}%
\end{figure}%

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libe
\begin{figure}[H]%
  \begin{centering}%
    \includegraphics[width=8cm]{example-image}
    \figcaption{Main window}
  \end{centering}%
\end{figure}%

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libe
\begin{figure}[H]%
  \begin{centering}%
    \includegraphics[width=8cm]{example-image}
    \figcaption{Main window}
  \end{centering}%
\end{figure}%

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libe
\begin{figure}[H]%
  \begin{centering}%
    \includegraphics[width=8cm]{example-image}
    \figcaption{Main window}
  \end{centering}%
\end{figure}%

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libe
\begin{figure}[H]%
  \begin{centering}%
    \includegraphics[width=8cm]{example-image}
    \figcaption{Main window}
  \end{centering}%
\end{figure}%

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libe
\begin{figure}[H]%
  \begin{centering}%
    \includegraphics[width=8cm]{example-image}
    \figcaption{Main window}
  \end{centering}%
\end{figure}%

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libe
\begin{figure}[H]%
  \begin{centering}%
    \includegraphics[width=8cm]{example-image}
    \figcaption{Main window}
  \end{centering}%
\end{figure}%

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libe
\begin{figure}[H]%
  \begin{centering}%
    \includegraphics[width=8cm]{example-image}
    \figcaption{Main window}
  \end{centering}%
\end{figure}%

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libe
\begin{figure}[H]%
  \begin{centering}%
    \includegraphics[width=8cm]{example-image}
    \figcaption{Main window}
  \end{centering}%
\end{figure}%

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libe
\begin{figure}[H]%
  \begin{centering}%
    \includegraphics[width=8cm]{example-image}
    \figcaption{Main window}
  \end{centering}%
\end{figure}%

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libe
\begin{figure}[H]%
  \begin{centering}%
    \includegraphics[width=8cm]{example-image}
    \figcaption{Main window}
  \end{centering}%
\end{figure}%

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libe
\begin{figure}[H]%
  \begin{centering}%
    \includegraphics[width=8cm]{example-image}
    \figcaption{Main window}
  \end{centering}%
\end{figure}%

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libe
\begin{figure}[H]%
  \begin{centering}%
    \includegraphics[width=8cm]{example-image}
    \figcaption{Main window}
  \end{centering}%
\end{figure}%

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libe
\begin{figure}[H]%
  \begin{centering}%
    \includegraphics[width=8cm]{example-image}
    \figcaption{Main window}
  \end{centering}%
\end{figure}%

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,                                                            vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida                                                       mauris. Nam arcu libe
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libe

\end{document}
```

- How to keep te figures in plce without the amount of white space around it

Comment: You can use `\raggedbottom`, if you really want that. Note that there exists no `centering` environment. It should be just `\centering`. It's only a happy coincidence if no errors appear.

Comment: See if result of using `\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=8cm]{example-image}
    \caption{Main window}
\end{figure}` is acceptable for you.

Comment: @zarko thanks for the suggestion, sorry doesn't work for me at the example I get on page 2 already an out of place image.

Comment: @campa strange that I didn't get a warning about the `\begin{centering}`

Comment: @campa the `\raggedbottom` looks promising have to do a number of tests

Comment: As I said, it's a happy coincidence: `\begin{foo}` just checks that `\foo` is defined (and in this case `\centering` _is_ defined), and `\end{foo}` expands to `\csname endfoo\endcsname`, and if `\endfoo` isn't defined this expands as `\relax` and nothing happens.

Comment: @campa I'm not a fan of such happy coincidences it is nice that it happens but hides possible real problems and can give hard to explain results.

Comment: @campa did a test and it looks quite OK to me. I placed the `raggedbottom` directly after the `begin{document} or is there a better place? Maybe you could also create an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @campa in the comments to the question an option is the usage of the command `\raggedbottom`.
I used the `\raggedboom directly after the \begin{document}` and this is working fine for me.

So I use:

```
...
\begin{document}
\raggedbottom
...
```